# Retirar extensão .php exceto de um arquivo

Tags: php, htaccess

Olá!

Tenho meu sistema em php, adicionei o arquivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Funcionou muito bem, mas eu queria que não retirasse a extensão só da index.php

Agradeço antecipadamente

Comment: é complicado mudar o contexto da pergunta depois de respondida. Sua alteração mudou um bocado o sentido fo que foi perguntado. Isso é um desperdício do tempo dos colegas que param para ler e ajudar, recomendo que na próxima, procure elaborar melhor para que você já obtenha o que quer.

Comment: Realmente eu não me atentei, mas assim vou aprendendo, obrigado pela dica

Comment: duplicou com essa nova: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desta forma pode resolver para você. Veja:

```
# index.php > index (visível, exceto para index.php)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Veja essa [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974317/2570426).

> Arquivos .htaccess oferecem um meio de fazer mudanças nas
>   configurações por diretório.

**Referência**

- [Tutorial do Apache: arquivos .htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: e da pasta funções  também rsrs tipo sistema/funcoes dentro dessa pasta também os arquivos permanerem com as extensões

Comment: @Carlos seria um adicional da pergunta ou poderia ser outra pergunta? hehe

Comment: é porque eu não soube me expressar rs

Comment: @Carlos tente em outras perguntas não acrescentar nada que vá influenciar nas respostas dadas. Não é muito interessante, porque na maioria das vezes invalida a resposta.

Comment: blz. Obrigado! Desculpa ai