# Retirar extensão de arquivos php, menos de um pasta

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho o arquivo .htaccess e quero tirar as extensões de arquivos menos dos seguintes: index.php e da pasta sistema/funcoes/ que é a pas onde estão meus processamentos

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Retirar extensão .php exceto de um arquivo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180220/retirar-extens%c3%a3o-php-exceto-de-um-arquivo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um novo arquivo .htaccess na pasta que você deseja ignorar, com:

```
 RewriteEngine Off
```

E outro na raiz com

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! Deu certo